# Op-Amp unusual symbol

Tags: operational-amplifier, symbol

I find this circuit in an old book.

Regardless what is the task of this circuit, i wonder why the op amp symbol is unusual(curved)?

[image]

This is the datasheet of LM301A: http://www.utm.edu/staff/leeb/LM301.pdf

But the other circuit **in the same book** using the traditional symbol for the op amp

[image]

Comment: The curved symbol was an early depiction used to denote the op amp device, but that dropped out of fashion sometime in the 60's if memory serves.

Comment: I believe Philbrick Nexus used that symbol; they made lots of money selling a varactor-diode-bridge discrete-transistor opamp; that company was acquired by Henry Singleton, with Teledyne Philbrick the subsidiary; Bob Pease worked at Philbrick Nexus, as discussed in one of his Pease Porrige articles for EDN magazine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just an older style of drawing that has since dropped out of common usage. It doesn't mean anything special about the opamp.